# Building a Generalized Linear Mixed Model in SAS

Tags: sas, glmm

I am building a generalized linear mixed model in SAS.  Unfortunately, this is the first time I’m working with GLMMs and I am not very familiar with SAS.  I have been using proc GLIMMIX.  I have data from 4 sites, each specified with a 4 letter code in the variable site.  Each site was sampled 11 times.  A crossover design was used for treatment, so 2 sites were treated for the first 5 weeks of the study, and the other 2 sites were treated for the last 6 weeks of the study.  I’ve incorporated this into the model with a variable called order with a value 1 for treatment 1st and 2 for treatment 2nd, and a variable called treatment that reads yes when treatment was present and no when treatment was absent.  My response variable should be normally distributed. My current code is:

```
proc glimmix data=data;

class Treatment Site Order;

model Response = Treatment Order Site;

random Site;

random Order;

run;
```

Is this too simplistic?  My goal is to figure out what effect treatment, order, and site had on the response variable and to determine which variables are necessary in the model.  I know I will have to run the model multiple times with different combinations of variables and compare AIC values to determine which variables are necessary (unless there is a way to do this in SAS?).  Do I need to change any of the other default parameters?  Do I need to make Site and/or Order a random_residual variable instead?  Thank you!  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if the response is normal maybe you don´t need a GLM. What is "Response" this is basic questions that need to be answered before going into generalized (non-normal-response) models. Since you have samples over time probably is a good idea to consider also a mixed model approach in order to count for correlation among measurements within an experimental unit. Loos at PROC Mixed and NLMIXED

Cheers

H. Gilabert
PUC de Chile, Dept. of Ecosystems & Environment